how to pass through css styles with Pandoc to html
I am looking to convert docbook xml input to html using pandoc 3.0 on windows 10.
How do I get pandoc to recognize text colors or other text styles? My docbooc xml input is
 <section id="body1">
  <title>Section with a title</title>
 <para>
 In the year 
<emphasis role="red">1878</emphasis> I took my degree of Doctor of Medicine of the University of London, and proceeded to Netley to go through the course prescribed for surgeons in the army. Having completed my studies there, I was duly attached to the Fifth Northumberland Fusiliers as Assistant Surgeon. The regiment was stationed in India at the time, and before I could join it, the second Afghan war had broken out.
</para>
</section>

I'd like 1878 to appear in red color, that is something like <span style=xxx>1878</span> where a supplied CSS recognizes xxx to mean font-color: red.
I am using
pandoc --standalone --embed-resources --css=my.css -f docbook \
    -t html -o foo.html`

FWIW, I am using a work laptop so installing additional XML/XSL software is probably not possible.
I have spent 2 days Googling this and I have read the Sagehill custom inline stuff but I cannot work out how to actually apply the custom inline styles. Also I'd like to do this by including XSL magic inside the docbook XML document if this is at all possible.
In all my searching the SageHill documentation
here
and SO question 73652391 probably came closest to what I wanted. But unless I'm missing something it appears as if the SageHill stuff requires xsltproc to work, ie Pandoc cannot do what xsltproc can do. Something like SO question 47474222 will also work I guess but I cannot work out how to do it.
I have read and re-read literally dozens of SO questions but they all seem to refer to Markdown input which is not an option for me. I am converting a library of old XML documents to produce HTML and to do a bunch of other tasks so Markdown input etc is not an option for me.

The main issue here is that pandoc preserves the structure of documents, but not formatting details. Text color is considered a formatting detail. This kind of information is already lost in the first step, when the document is being read-in, so there is no way to preserve it in the remaining steps. The loss of information is due to one of pandoc's limitations, see here.
One option could be to find something that those colored texts have in common, and to then apply the methods from the mentioned Q&As. E.g., if all emphasized elements that contain only digits were to be colored in red, then a Lua filter like this should do:
function Emph (em)
  if pandoc.utils.stringify(em):match '^[0-9]*$' then
    return pandoc.Span(em, {style="font-color:red"})
  end
end


Your (very cogent and informative) answer produces <span font-color:red> <em> 1878 </em></span> and I wonder if it is possible to write a filter that produces just <span xyz> 1878 </span> so the output appears just red, not italics-red. More generally how can I write a lua-filter that recognizes some made-up xml tag like <textred> text </textred> and replaces that with just the span style? I am curious if lua-filters are used in pre-processing input xml or post-processing the resulting xml? (I am guessing the former.) TIA...

Removing the <em> is possible by changing the return line to pandoc.Span(em.content, ...). I can't answer the second question right away, that might be worth another post.
